How to pre - calculate logic on Quote to avoid multiple condition check in approval condition
I have multiple Advance approval rules with approval conditions that runs sequentially
The rules have become very condition heavy and I want to do some computation beforehand with a single variable and use it in all rules
Scenario - If the Sales Executive creates a Quote based on a discount threshold, the approvals are triggered to his peers in the above hierarchy
If Sales Executive creates Quote ( say 60% - he needs approval from evryone) - Rule 1 to Rule 6 - runs
If Regional Director Creates a Quote (say 60%) who is above in the hierarchy than Sales Executive then Rule 2 to Rule 6 runs, Rule 1 is skipped as he doesn't need approval from peers in lower hierarchy.
and so on
In order to achieve this I have to write OR conditions in each rules , which are making rules , condition heavy
Rule. 1  runs - Createdby Equals Sales Rep
Rule 2 runs - Createdby Equals Sales Rep OR Regional Dir
Rules 3  runs - Createdby Equals Sales Rep OR Regional Dir OR Geo Director
Rules 4  runs - Createdby Equals Sales Rep OR Regional Dir OR Geo Director oR Sector Director
and so on, How can I do this OR calculation in Quote itself
I have tried multiple ways, but the Approval Conditions don't support contains Operator
Can someone guide me?
